# Prepending some text to a WCF response message body

Tags: xml, wcf, xslt

I want to prepend the following text to the response body of a WCF operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="transform.xslt" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

What is the best way to do this?

An additional requirement is that the XSLT filename should be spec'd using an attribute on the operation method.

I am trying to do this using a IDispatchMesssageInspector, but I do not know how to get access to the MethodInfo for the operation so that I can read the filename from the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to use a custom MessageEncoder with its own MessageEncodingBindingElement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get the current operation method:

```
var context = OperationContext.Current;
string action = context.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
var operation = context.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations
    .First(o => o.Action == action);
Type hostType = context.Host.Description.ServiceType;
MethodInfo method = hostType.GetMethod(operation.Name);
```

Comment: And the operation context will be available in IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply?

Comment: This certainly got me closer, but I find that action == null. The only header present is the To header. This gives me the Uri that was called, now I just need a map of Uri to Operation...

Comment: With WebHttpBehaviour2 from the REST tookit