# Mapping a WCF request message to the underlying operation

Tags: wcf, request, operation

I need to know what operation is being invoked by examining a request Message object in an IDispatchMessageInspector.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no 100% sure way of doing this, because IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest() runs before the dispatcher has matched the message to an actual operation on the service. That said, if you're using the default [IDispatchOperationSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchoperationselector.aspx), then it's possible to build a map that matches SOAP Action names with operation names during ApplyDispatchBehavior(). I have a blog post that talks a little bit about this [here](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/operationdescriptionandthesoapaction).

There's a bit of an example of how to build this map on some code [here](http://quickcounters.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/43042?projectName=quickcounters#184671).

Comment: My aim is to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686246/prepending-some-text-to-a-wcf-response-message-body. Thanks for the input.